# Maps API not showing border which was visible is google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps API for my project.

```
var elevator;
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.50, -129.35),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
};
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

var address="CA,state"
$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
  var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
  new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
  });
});
```

**Google Maps CA in maps.google.com**

[image]

**In My App through API**

[image]

California Boundary is not shown in map which drawn through API. Any help will be useful.

Comment: The google maps api is not the same as maps.google.com (an app that is presumably build on the API) - if you want to show the border on your implementation, you'll have to draw it yourself: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API leaves to the user the job of implementing anything outside the basic features.

Google Maps shares a lot of features in common with Google Maps API but it has always had an edge over his little brother.

For this particular case, you could use a [google.maps.KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayer)  to display your desired boundaries. For this, you need a publicly available kml file. This means, if you find said kml, storing it in your public dropbox folder would suffice. Also, there's a size limit on kml files, so don't get carried away.

I guess you need more than just California, but here's an example just for CA

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 5,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -111),
    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
});

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                  url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3133731/kml/california.kml', 
                  map:map,
                  preserveViewport: true,
                  suppressInfoWindows: true
                });
```

Here: [I made you a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/zpr5njne/1/).